# How to redirect using fetch API?

Tags: python, django, redirect, fetch

I have a redirect view like this:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.remove_product(product)
    cart.save()
    message = Message(request)
    message.set(f'{product.name} has been removed from cart!')
    return redirect('shopping:cart')
```

I am trying to redirect to this views's response URL via `fetch` API:

```
remove.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let url = "{% url 'shopping:remove_from_cart' 123 %}".replace('123', e.target.id)
    fetch(url, {
        redirect: 'follow',
     })
     .then(response => console.log(response.status)) // logs 200
})
```

But the redirect does not happen. It works fine if I enter the url manually, though.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Given it returns 200, it should have followed the redirect. Note that a redirect has a 302 as status code. The API will thus, normally, make an extra GET request. But it will of course not change the "outer page".

Comment: Yes, it returns 200. The `console.log(response)` is `Response {type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart", redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}`. Not sure why the status is not 302, though.

Comment: @barciezicz: then it looks like it made a proper redirect. Likely it has a `response.body`?

Comment: Hmm, `console.log(response.body)` is `ReadableStream {locked: false}`. The `cart` view I am trying to redirect to returns `render(request, 'shopping/cart.html')`.

Comment: well that means you need to "read out" the stream. It is not that uncommon not to send the entire response if not necessary.

Comment: I'm no js expert but I don't think that `redirect:follow` does what you expect. As I understand it, it will just _internally_ follow the redirect so instead of the original 302 response it makes a second request and returns the response for this second request. IOW, the solution would be to not pass "redirect;follow" and instead get the redirection url from the original 302 response and use window.location to go to this new url.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thanks. Strangely, if I remove `redirect: 'follow'`, I get exactly same response. Nevertheless, the redirect URL is included in it, so I can extract it and use `window.location` as you suggested. Still, would be great if this could be achieved in a cleaner manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
remove.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let url = "{% url 'shopping:remove_from_cart' 123 %}".replace('123', e.target.id)

    fetch(url)
     .then(response => window.location.assign("redirect url here") <--- change here
})
```

you may need to do some adjustment in view according to your need.
But for sure you can redirect manually using **window.location.assign("url here")**

I know answer is late but hope it might help others